# "Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall" when I try to solve the "sum the largest n integers in the array" programming challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to come up with a solution to the

> Sum n largest integers in an array of integers where every integer is
>   between 0 and 9
>
> ```
> int SumNLargest(int* anData, int size, int n)
> ```

programming challenge prompt, a solution other than the obvious one of sorting a copy of the array and returning the sum of the last 9 elements.So I tried writing the linear solution below

```
#include <iostream>

int SumNLargest(int* anData, int size, int n)
{
// Sum n largest integers in an array of integers where every integer is between 0 and 9
    int cntArr [] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) ++cntArr[anData[i]];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        sum += (n - cntArr[i]) >= 0 ?  cntArr[i] * i : n * i;
        --n;
        if (n <= 0) break;
    }   
    return sum;
}


int main()
{
    int myArray [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 15};
    std::cout << SumNLargest(myArray, sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(int), 2);
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm getting the error

> Disallowed system call: SYS_socketcall

See: http://codepad.org/UILgXDzQ

Is this a problem with my logic? If so, where? Also, is there a more elegant linear solution that I should've done instead?

(And finally, I realize that my solution assumes `n >= size >= 1`, but I think the typical programming interview allows me to make that assumption so that I don't have to waste time writing a bunch of error handling for unexpected input)

Comment: the error is not related to your program. It seems to be an internal bug (?).

Comment: also you violate the requirement that the array contains values between 0 and 9 and you get undefined behavior because you access cntArr[anData[i]] where anData[i] is greater than 9, i.e. greater than the size of cndArr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behavior at

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
        ++cntArr[anData[i]];
```

when you access the eleventh element (`i = 10`) because `cntArr` has only 10 elements.
A memory checker such as AddressSanitizer would indicate you that immediately.

You're not really calling a system call to create a new socket but, as result of an undefined behavior, anything could happen.