# Why i am getting sum as output even i am not returning the value?

Tags: c, function, return

```
sum(int a,int b)
{
    int x;
    x = a+b;
}
int main()
{ 
    printf("%d",sum(2,3));
}
```

If i remove the `x` then it will return first parameter always, but I am not returning any value.

Comment: Because [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32132574/10077).

Comment: Upped as this question is nicely written with a compilable example. Remember, C gives you the ability to shoot yourself in the foot. That's why you need to follow the rules. And please use a compiler that will puke if a function doesn't have an explicit return type: that's been banned since C99.

Comment: What program from ms office you used to compile this?

Comment: @PetarVelev: Ahem! I have Microsoft Excel down as the best application ever written.

Comment: @Bathsheba Then you most likely haven't seen much programs really

Comment: @Edenia: I've seen enough. Sadly this ain't the site, but I can't resist. Care to state a couple of programs that you consider better?

Comment: @Bathsheba Gladly: notepad, windows itself and this: http://i46.tinypic.com/293hj6w.jpg

Comment: @Bathsheba Probably yes for its purpose. I had a different point there.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make use of a function call return value and the function does not have a `return` statement in it.

Directly quoting `C11`, chapter §6.9.1 (*for functions other than `main()`*, <sup>Footnote</sup>)

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

---

Footnote:

From chapter §5.1.2.2.3

> [...] reaching the `}` that terminates the
>   `main` function returns a value of 0.

Comment: Other than main().

Comment: @Bathsheba true indeed, but recursive call to main is not a very good idea, either, :)

Comment: Worth adding to the answer though to make it correct? Note that calling main from itself is UB in C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba there you go. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba you gotta teach me the trick to the no-printing characters, please. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum(int a,int b)
 {
     int x;
     x = a+b;
     return x;
 }
 int main()
 { 
     printf("%d",sum(2,3));
 }`
```

this is how your code should look, you're getting results *sometimes* as `x` is a local variable and its value persists on the stack until it's overwritten, so you may end up getting the value you want, or you may end up getting some garbage