# How to fix my function popFront for my list?

Tags: c++

My program is a list of cities, it's good but when I call to `popFront()`, I don't know why but it doesn't work, then I call any function and the program is over.

```
City* popFront(Nodo*& header, Nodo*& trailer) {
    City* libras;
    if (inicio) {
        strcpy(libras->Name,inicio->dato.Name );
        libras->Num = header->dato.Num;
        Nodo* aux = header;
        header= header->next;
                header->previous= NULL;
        delete aux;
        if (!header) trailer = NULL;
    }
    return libras;
}
```

```
void read(Nodo*& head) {    
    Nodo* aux = head;
    int pos = 1;
    while (pos <= node_count) {
        cout << "pos" << pos << endl;
        cout << "Name> " << aux->dato.Name << endl;
        cout << "NUm> " << aux->dato.Num << endl;
        aux = aux->next;
        pos++;
    }
    if (node_count == 0)cout << "Empty list" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Note that you're not programming in C but C++.

Comment: Yes, tag= c++,I'm making a list of cities in c ++ with c syntax

Comment: Are your nodes already allocated by the time `read()` is called?

Comment: In the `popFront` function, where do `libras` point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure this is the only problem, but this right here is wrong:

```
City* libras;
```

You need to allocate it before you use it, like this:

```
City* libras = new City;
```

Otherwise, something like `strcpy(libras->Name,inicio->dato.Name );` will fall and crash hard. That's because it's UB ([Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen)) to access a pointer to memory that is unallocated.

Of course, you will need to `delete` it when you're done with it, but you seem to know and understand that already based on your other code:

```
delete libras; // Or wherever the returned pointer gets stored
```

Comment: Yes!!, 
I appreciate it, I didn't realize I was using a pointer, it works now.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your issue, feel free to upvote it or accept this answer by clicking the check-mark next to it.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience