# behavior of c++ code changes depending on the compiler

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I’m really new to c and c++

I tried to experiment with structs to create a list-like structure that can contain float and lists, basically.

This code compiles, but it behaves differently depending on the compiler:

- with the latest version of visual studio community, it outputs `5` and then `0`.
- with an [online shell](http://www.cpp.sh/), I get `5` and then `5`

The one I would want to get is the second one when the vector gets passed through the function.

here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Box {
    Box(char t) {
        type = t;
    }
    union Value {
        float number;
        vector<Box>* elements;
    };
    Value value;
    char type;
};

Box newBox() {
    Box aBox('l');

    vector<Box> newVec;
    newVec.assign(5, Box('n'));


    aBox.value.elements = &newVec;
    cout << aBox.value.elements->size() << "\n";
    return aBox;

}

int main()
{
    Box test = newBox();
    cout << test.value.elements->size();  // this is not always working nicely
}
```

Where does that come from?

Is there something wrong with my code?

And is there a better way to create this kind of structure?

Comment: "This code compiles, but he behaves differently depending on the compiler:" There's usually only two reasons for this: 1) a compiler bug or 2) [Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen). I'll have to look closer at your code to help figure out which is at fault here.

Comment: The lifetime of `newVec` ends when `newBox` returns. Dereferencing a pointer to it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Chipster -- or unspecified behavior: valid code whose meaning is determined by the implementation; or implementation-defined behavior: valid code whose meaning is determined by the implementation and documented by the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this line:

```
aBox.value.elements = &newVec;
```

you are storing the address of a local variable. When you return from the `newBox` function, that variables dies, and then accessing that memory via the pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there something wrong with my code?

@cigien's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62334372/1593077) explains what's wrong.

> And is there a better way to create this kind of structure?

1. Not related to your bug, but - [don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C1171.2617).
2. Avoid using raw pointers when you don't really need them; and certainly don't [use them to transfer ownership](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-raw).
3. Use vocabulary types such as std::variant and std::optional instead of raw unions.

So, Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

struct Box {
    struct Item { float value; };
    using Boxes = std::vector<Box>;
    struct Empty {};

    Box(char t) : type(t) { }

    auto& item() &            { return std::get<Item>(contents); }
    const auto& item() const  { return std::get<Item>(contents); }

    auto& boxes()             { return std::get<Boxes>(contents); }
    const auto& boxes() const { return std::get<Boxes>(contents); }

    std::variant<Empty, Item, Boxes> contents { Empty{} };
    char type;
};

Box newBox() {
    Box aBox('l');

    Box::Boxes subBoxes;
    subBoxes.assign(5, Box('n'));

    aBox.contents = std::move(subBoxes);
    std::cout << "aBox has " << test.boxes().size() << " sub-boxes.\n";
    return aBox;
}

int main()
{
    Box test = newBox();
    std::cout << test.boxes().size() << '\n';
}
```

This is better - no pointers, and it's clearer what you can put in a box. However, note that making assumptions about the current active kind of element ina variant is usually a bad idea, so try to avoid `std::get()` in favor of `std:visit()` usually, to be on the safe side. Also, perhaps a method telling you how many items there in the box (in the shallow and the deep sense) could make sense. Read up on [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) if you want to go in that direction.