# How do you make the use of std::variants more "palatable", syntax-wise?

Tags: c++, c++17, idioms, syntactic-sugar, std-variant

This is motivated by an answer I gave a newbie user, where I suggested they use an [`std::variant`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62334724/1593077) instead of a union.

With a union, you may have something like the following:

```
struct Box {
    struct Item { float value; };
    using Boxes = std::vector<Box>;

    union Value {
        Item item;
        Boxes boxes;
    };

    Value contents;
    std::string label;
};
```

(not exactly what the original question had, I'm taking some poetic license here.) and with a variant, the class might look like this:

```
struct Box {
    struct Item { float value; };
    using Boxes = std::vector<Box>;

    std::variant<Item, Boxes> contents;
    std::string label;
};
```

The thing is, that with the first variant, I can write

```
if (box.contents.boxes.size() > 2) { foo(); }
```

and provided that I've already established there are going to be sub-boxes, this will work.

With an `std::variant`, I have to write:

```
if (std::get<Boxes>(box.contents).size() > 2) { foo(); }
```

I feel the second version is much less readable, a bit confusing, and quite distracting. Plus - I have to know the type of `boxes`.

What can I do, in my code, to spare my users the need to make this kind of `std::get()` calls, and make their lives more pleasant?

Comment: Prefer using `std::visit` instead of `std::get` when accessing `std::variant`s

Comment: @Mestkon: Generally, that's valid advice. But suppose I know which is the active type.

Comment: The `if` using `std::variant` is not doing the same as the `union` one: it does an unneeded extra check since you have already established there are going to be sub-boxes. Since there is no good way to avoid that check, `std::variant` is not general enough to replace `union`. Thus I avoid recommending it. The compile times, codegen and verbose syntax do not help, either.

Comment: @Acorn: 1. You're right about the extra check. 2. Theoretically, the compiler can realize, at least in simple cases, that the check is unnecessary and remove it, but I'm not sure that happens in practice.

Answer (score 5):

Just add some accessors wrapping `std::get`s:

```
struct Box {
    struct Item { float value; };
    using Boxes = std::vector<Box>;

    std::variant<Item, Boxes> contents;
    std::string label;

    decltype(auto) item()       { return std::get<Item>(contents); }
    decltype(auto) item() const { return std::get<Item>(contents); }

    decltype(auto) boxes()       { return std::get<Boxes>(contents); }
    decltype(auto) boxes() const { return std::get<Boxes>(contents); }
};
```

And then it goes:

```
if (box.boxes().size() > 2) { foo(); }
```

Comment: You'd better make the non-const getters return an lvalue reference, not a copy... but +1.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. `decltype(auto)`, need to remember it does that.

Answer (score 1):

How about "visiting" methods? Something like this:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;


struct Box {
    struct Item { float value; };
    using Boxes = std::vector<Box>;

    std::variant<Item, Boxes> contents;
    std::string label;

    decltype(auto) size() const {
        return std::visit(overloaded {
            [](const Item&)        { return 1; }
            [](const Boxes& boxes) { return boxes.size(); } // non-recursive
        }, *this);
    }
};
```

and then you write:

```
if (box.size() > 2 ) { foo(); }
```

?

Comment: what exactly is a `const Empty&`?

Comment: @PatrickParker: A copy-paste from something I suggested in the motivating post which shouldn't have carried over into this answer... :-( removed it.