# Reading 23 bytes even the buffer is of 10bytes

Tags: c

I know it's very dumb but I really don't get what the heck is happening here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getinput()
{
    char buf[10];
    int rv = read(0, buf, 1000);
    printf("\nNumber of bytes read are %d\n", rv);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    getinput();
    return 0;
}
```

I can't understand how this `read()` function is working.

```
read(0, buf, 1000)
```

Also, the buf is 10 bytes long why it is taking 23 bytes?

Comment: C have no bound checking. The `read` function only know what you pass to it, and if you say that the buffer can fit `1000` bytes then that what it will try to read. Going out of bounds of an array (or other allocated memory) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: See [Does "Undefined Behavior" really permit *anything* to happen ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen)

Comment: Thanks for that information but why it gives segmentation fault only after 23bytes why not at 11 i get it there is no bound but we should get a segmentation fault at 11 bytes

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar because it's _undefined bahaviour_ which includes "apparently working fine"

Comment: okay so how can I fix this I am new to C so what should I do here

Comment: You fix it by always being careful to create buffers of the proper size and not writing outside of the bounds of allocated memory.

Comment: hmm i see there is actually no permanent solution i have to take guess actually

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar a permanent solution to what?

Comment: Like I mean if I want that person gives any size of bytes and it tells us how many bytes user have entered

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar OK, that's a totally different question. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Array-pointer equivalence

In C, an array like the variable `buf` in your example is just a pointer to the memory address of the first allocated byte.

You can print the value of this pointer:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[10];
    printf("Address of the first byte of buf: %p\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```txt
Address of the first byte of buf: 0x7ffd3699bfb6
```

### Pointer arithmetic

When you write something into this buffer with an instruction like

```c
buf[3] = 'Z';
```

It is in fact translated to

```c
*(buf+3) = 'Z';
```

It means "add `3` to the value of the pointer `buf` and store the character `'Z'` at the resulting address".

Nothing is stopping you from storing the character `'Z'` at any given address. You can store it before or after the address pointed to by `buf` without any restriction. If the address you choose happen to be the address of another variable, it cannot produce a segmentation fault (the address is valid).

In C, you can even write the character `'Z'` at the address `123456` if you like:

```c
int main(void) {
    char *address = (char *)123456;
    *address = 'Z';
    return 0;
}
```

The fact that your buffer is 10 bytes long does not change that. You cannot "fix" this because **writing anything at any memory location is a fundamental feature of the C programming language**. The only "fix" I can think of would be to use another language.

### File descriptors opened at program startup

In your exemple, you pass the value `0` as the first argument of the function `read()`. It seems that this value corresponds to the [file descriptor of the standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)). This file descriptor is automatically opened at program startup (normally you get such a file descriptor as the result of a call to the function `open()`). So, if you get 23 read bytes, it means that you typed in 23 characters on your keyboard during the program execution (for instance, 22 letters and 1 newline character).

It would be better to use the macro name of the standard input file descriptor:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getinput()
{
    char buf[10];
    int rv = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 10);
    printf("\nNumber of bytes read are %d\n", rv);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    getinput();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to make my concept more clear it means that this behavior can be changed when we will recompile it also the fact it gives segmentation fault has nothing to do with computer right ?

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar : Even without recompiling the program, the behavior can change between two executions of the same binary program. And no, the fact that it gives a segmentation fault does not mean that the computer has a problem, it just means that your program has a bug.

Comment: ok got it and i know it does not mean computer has error i thought it has something to with computer buffer register anyways thanks my friend

Comment: Thanks for ur help my friend

Answer (score 1):

your sample is a perfect example of a buffer overflow.

read(0, buff, 1000) will most probably corrupt the memory (stack on your case).

Read will take the start address of your buf pointer and will write those 23 bytes in your case... if there are some other structures on the memory they will be overwritten by those 13 bytes and can lead to very unwanted behavior (maybe even crashes of you application)

Comment: I know it will overflow because buf it is of 10 bytes but why it is writing 23 bytes and also what do you mean by other structures.
Thanks

Comment: read has this signature

ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);

in your case count is 1000, that means you potentially allow read to write 1000 bytes into the buffer..

since only 23 bytes can be read from the fd it reads only 23

Comment: but my friend why 23 it's zero in place of fd

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar How do you run the program?

Comment: ./a.out Then it stops for input

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar and what is your input?

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar; so the programm does everything what is is expected to do...

fd 0 is the *stdin* file descriptor of you process...

Comment: Yea almost the only mistake is that 1000

Comment: you could solve this with either define a constant which you use for the allocation of the array and as last parameter 

or replace 1000 with sizeof(buf)

Answer (score 1):

C gives the responsibility to handle memory correctly to the programmer. So there is no bounds checking.

You call `read()` with 3 arguments:

1. The file handle, in your case "0".
2. The pointer to the array of bytes to fill with the bytes read from the file, in your case `buf`.
3. The size of this array, in your case "1000".

Apparently the file has only 23 bytes, which is less or equal to 1000, so `read()` returns this value.

*Note: But before, it happily wrote all these 23 bytes into the array. Since your buffer has just a capacity of 10 bytes, the memory after it gets overwritten. This is called "buffer overflow" and is a common error, abused for evil attacks, or possibly leading to crashes or malfunction (Thanks, ikegami!).*

To fix this error, I recommend to change the read into:

```c
    read(0, buf, sizeof buf);
```

This way your are always giving the right size to `read()`. (If you declare `buf` as an array, of course.)

Comment: Re "*abused for evil attacks*", Or more commonly, a reason programs crash and/or malfunction.

Comment: I get it it Will wrote 23 but it will not give segmentation fault even after 12 bytes or 13 but only 23 and on one machine it's giving segmentation fault at 21 bytes

Comment: @ArslanIftikhar undefined behaviour is undefined. If you write outside of a buffer then anything can happen: for example nothing, a crash, program behaves strangely even later, some other unrelated variables change apparently for no reason etc.