# what does my reversed array add random characters in C

Tags: arrays, c, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I wrote code to reverse an array after in C.
I'm using C17. In the code the user is asked to input a word, the word then is put into an array
and then reversed.
The code works for the exception that it adds some random characters and I couldn't figure out why it does that.

Can you help me with that?

Here is my code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 80

void inputtoarray(char input[]);                //Take the input from user and put it into an array
void reverseinput(char input1[]);


int main(){

    char input[MAXLINE];
    inputtoarray(input);
    reverseinput(input);


    return 0;
}

void inputtoarray(char input[]){
    int c;                  //to hold the indiviual characters before going into the array
                            //int was used over char because I want to be able to hold EOF
    int i;                  //i is the array counter
    //ask the user to type in a word
    printf("Please type in a word:\n");

    for(i=0; (c=getchar()) != '\n'; ++i){
        input[i] = c;
    }

}

void reverseinput(char input1[]){
    int cinput;
    int coutput;
    char temp[MAXLINE];         //define a temporary array

    //count the number of characters in the array
    for (cinput=0; input1[cinput] != '\0'; ++cinput){

    }
    coutput=cinput;

    //the reversing process. Here cinput holds the number of the last character
    for (cinput=0; coutput > 0; --coutput, ++cinput ){
        temp[coutput] = input1[cinput];
        //input1[coutput] = temp[coutput];
        //printf("%s", temp);
    }
    input1 = temp;
    printf("%s", input1);


}
```

Comment: you are not terminating `input` with `\0`

Comment: Please provide an input, expected output and actual output so we have an example we know will incorrectly work from your testing

Comment: look at your code; where do you add a NUL terminator to your input? (hint: you don't). It's often safer to pass a length than rely on '\0'

Comment: @IrAM how would I terminate with \0

Comment: @TheGrandJ for example if you run the code and type hello you get `olleh

Comment: Learn to use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) with [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 3):

The function `inputtoarray` does not input a string. As a result this loop

```
for (cinput=0; input1[cinput] != '\0'; ++cinput){

}
```

within the function `reverseinput` results in undefined behavior.

The function `inputtoarray` can look for example the following way

```
void inputtoarray( char input[], size_t n )
{
    int c;                  //to hold the indiviual characters before going into the array
                            //int was used over char because I want to be able to hold EOF
    size_t i = 0;           //i is the array counter
    
    //ask the user to type in a word
    printf("Please type in a word:\n");

    for ( ; i + 1 < n && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i )
    {
        input[i] = c;
    }

    input[i] = '\0';    
}
```

and called like

```
inputtoarray( input, MAXLINE );
```

Moreover this loop

```
for (cinput=0; coutput > 0; --coutput, ++cinput ){
    temp[coutput] = input1[cinput];
    //input1[coutput] = temp[coutput];
    //printf("%s", temp);
}
```

does not set the element `temp[0]` due to the condition `coutput > 0`. So the first element of the array `temp` has an indeterminate value.

And this assignment

```
 input1 = temp;
```

does not make a sense because it changes the local variable `input` instead of changing the array pointed to by the pointer (parameter) `input`.

Without using standard string functions the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 80

void inputtoarray( char input[], size_t n )
{
    int c;                  //to hold the indiviual characters before going into the array
                            //int was used over char because I want to be able to hold EOF
    size_t i = 0;           //i is the array counter
    
    //ask the user to type in a word
    printf("Please type in a word:\n");

    for ( ; i + 1 < n && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i )
    {
        input[i] = c;
    }

    input[i] = '\0';    
}

void reverseinput( char input[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;
    
    while ( input[n] ) ++n;
    
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < --n; i++ )
        {
            char c = input[i];
            input[i] = input[n];
            input[n] = c;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    char input[MAXLINE];
    
    inputtoarray( input, MAXLINE );
    reverseinput( input );
    
    puts( input );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Please type in a word:
Hello
olleH
```

Comment: inputtoarray was meant to take the user's input and put it in an array. Do you take into consideration that the code gives me the expected output but with added random characters

Comment: @Sp1cyChef And what? What is unclear with my answer?

Comment: I don't understand. If all that is wrong with my code how come I'm so close to the wanted final result. I'm trying to learn C here so If you can give me more basic details I would appreciate that

Comment: @Sp1cyChef The code has undefined behavior. The uninitialized array input can contain any garbage but you rely on that it contains a terminating zero character.

Comment: See [Does "Undefined Behavior" really permit *anything* to happen ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32132574/3422102)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I tried to use the inputtoarray you suggested and I'm still getting 'olleh when I type hello. Can you edit my code to make it work so I can see where I went wrong. I'm not familiar with undefined behavior so I will have to read about it more