# Why returning a pointer to a struct initialized without malloc doesn't fail in C++

Tags: c++

I saw this code in C++ - it is used to add two linked lists.

The **addTwoNumbers** function defines a **head** which is a struct pointer and its **next** member is a struct. Eventually the function returns the **next** member of **head**. Both were initialized on the stack (without using malloc) so how is it possible that the returned value points to a valid address after function execution frame was removed from the stack?
Thanks ahead for explanation :)

```
struct ListNode
{
  int val;
  ListNode *next;
  ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
  ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
  ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};

ListNode *somFunc()
{
  ListNode *tail = new ListNode(2);
  ListNode *head = new ListNode(12, tail);
  return head->next;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ListNode *res = somFunc();
  return 0;
};
```

Comment: The logic in the shown code is quite ...hard to decipher. But in general case, [undefined behavior means anything can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132574/does-undefined-behavior-really-permit-anything-to-happen), so just because the shown code doesn't crash or give the wrong results does not mean that it's working correctly.

Comment: `ListNode` has no destructor so (1) it's going to leak and (2) this lets all the saved stack pointers like `ListNode two(4, &three);`  work, as `next` is never deleted.

Comment: @OP *I saw this code in C++ - it is used to add two linked lists.*  -- FYI -- You could have eliminated all of the code in that function and replaced it with: `ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {ListNode *head = new ListNode(0);  return head->next;}` -- There would have been no difference in the reasoning why `next` is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ListNode three(3);
  ListNode two(4, &three);
  ListNode one(2, &two);

  ListNode six(3);
  ListNode five(4, &six);
  ListNode four(2, &five);
```

All of these nodes have automatic storage indeed. And when the function `main` returns, those nodes are destroyed. However, you aren't returning any pointers from `main`.

---

The nodes created in `addTwoNumbers` have dynamic storage:

```
ListNode *head = new ListNode(0);
...
curr->next = new ListNode(sum);
...
curr->next = new ListNode(1);
```

These objects exist until the pointers are explicitly freed using `delete`. Thus, the pointers remain valid outside of that function. Those pointers are never `delete`d in the program though, so it leaks memory.

Now, the answer to your question:

> Why returning a pointer to a struct initialized without malloc doesn't fail in C++

1. You're returning a pointer that remains valid even after the function returns.
2. Returning a pointer that will become invalid won't "fail". The returned pointer simply becomes invalid.
3. Returning a pointer may only "fail" if it has an indeterminate value and even then only because behaviour of the program is undefined, and thus "failure" isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `head` nor `next` is initialized on the stack. They both use dynamic memory using `new`. In C++, `malloc` is generally avoided.

That being said, there's quite a few memory leaks in the code (as RichardCritten pointed out in the comments). Not sure where you received this code, but it is quite bad.