# I don't understand why my integer values are changing in C++

Tags: c++, integer, cout

My code is the following (C++) and returns 0, 8, and then 0 for each integer. I have no idea why?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

int earth;
std::cout << earth << '\n';

int fire;
std::cout << fire << '\n';

int water;
std::cout << water;

return 0;
}
```

I expected all 3 int values to return 0.

Comment: that's "#include <iostream>" at the top, my post removed it for some reason

Comment: too add, if i create an array before the first integer i get a value of 32759 for the first int, I thought newly created int should all return 0?

Comment: You never initialize any of the variables before using hem, so they contain whatever random content is at that memory location. **NEVER** use variables without initializing them. **NEVER**, under any circumstances. Have I made it clear enough that you should ***NEVER USE UNINITIALIZED VARIABLES*** yet? And `int` variables are not *created* - they are not objects. You've simply declared storage for something the size of an `int`. You've told the compiler *this is a name for an `int` size value*, but you've not assigned that value yet.

Comment: C++ does NOT initialize variables, it leaves the values them as they were in memory.. Try `int earth{1}` or `int earth = 1;`  or even `int earth{}` to initializze the value. The reason for not initializing is that it takes time and is not always needed (e.g. if your code reads a value from IO). And C++ has this paradigm : Do not pay for what you do not use

Comment: Well I watched this coding tutorial and it seemed they did the same thing and had no problems at all.  Are you saying i should just say int earth = 0; everytime?

Comment: Yes you should do that every time. Initialize before first use. And this can be reading from input, eg. `int i;  std::cin >> i; std::cout << i;`

Comment: Yes Ken White.  I was just following along a tutorial and they had no issues, i guess I was wondering why my environment was different using the same code, but i understand your answer, thank you.

Comment: *"Well I watched this coding tutorial..."* **That is why C++ must be learnt using a** [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead of by watching random online video tutorials.

Comment: @NDepth which tutorial? Most youtube videos on that are sh*tty and the youtuber don't even understand the C++ standard. Please [get a good book and read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714)

Comment: I understand -user12002570, just curious as to why I had issues, but they ran the code without, but it seems i am annoying everyone trying to understand that part so thank you all again.

Comment: [Undefined behavior means anything can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/995714), including the program working as expected or making [nasal daemons flying](https://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) https://stackoverflow.com/q/32132574/995714

Comment: thank you phuclv that explains my secondary question, thanks all, I will be sure to initialize variables from now on!

Comment: C++ zero initializes the fundamental types like `int` and `double` in special circumstances. Until you know what the special circumstances are, and when they apply, assume that they are NOT initialized. A good compiler will help with this if you ask it. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/1WcGGGWeY Note all the compiler options used. The more you get the compiler to do, the more sleep you get.

Comment: @NDepth – It is possible that the video you viewed was using "global" variables, i.e., variables declared with _file-level_ or _namespace_ scope. Those are variables that are declared outside of any function or class. In the absence of an explicit initializer, those guys are guaranteed to be zero-initialized.

Comment: "Local" variables are a different story. Those are variables declared within a function, class, or block, and they are not guaranteed to be initialized. That's what you ran into in your program above. Using one of them, before it has been initialized, results in undefined behavior, i.e., behavior that is not guaranteed by the C++ Standard.

Comment: @NDepth The fact is that we see beginners making the same basic mistakes in C++ over and over again. The issue must be the quality of learning materials the beginner is using. You really cannot learn C++ by watching youtube videos, or by analogy with other languages, or by guesswork, but we see beginners trying to do this all the time. Hence the frustration. Learning C++ requires study, and a good book is the best place to start.

Comment: turn on warnings and fix them https://godbolt.org/z/aKE64zsT5.

Comment: The downside of the global variable is any part of the program can at any time change the global variable and that can change the amount of the program you have to inspect when debugging dramatically. An even more interesting  problem is the [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof). Use globals with great caution.